# redirect to the same controller and action method in sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have a function that is doing a serious of activities and at one stage it shows a pop up. Now, my requirement is, once the user clicks OK on this warning pop up, it should resume its operation on this action method further.

They implemented it in the MVC somehow. However, in the new Sitecore MVC, we dont support RedirectToAction.

Is there an equivalent way to redirect to this controller and particular action method? I need something equivalent of this

```
RedirectToAction("SubmitDetails", "DetailsController");
```

in the Sitecore MVC

Comment: Hi, what version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: @DenisRadinski: Latest 8.1

Comment: Btw, when you use RedirectToAction you don't pass in the Controller part, it should be RedirectToAction("SubmitDetails", "Details"); Can you be more specific on what you are trying to do, i have hard time understanding exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Deevinee do you have a "pure" controller or a controller rendering? To understand you correctly, you have 2 actions in your controller when the user clicks "ok", you want to execute the second action right?

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl: I have multiple actions. But my scenario is, there is already an action getting executed and in the middle of that, there is a pop up that's being displayed which is nothing but a warning message pop up for our business funcionality. Once user clicks OK, it should resume its execution from the place it left within the same action.

Comment: @Deevinee hm I think this is not the way how the web works. Also this is not possible with RedirectToAction(). I suggest you split this into two actions. And after confirm of the warning, you reload the page (or redirect to another) and execute the second action.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer; no there isn't a way to do exactly what you ask for here.

Reason being; Sitecore Controller Renderings are meant to return something visible/renderable - at their core they are still "renderings" to the Sitecore system.

You need to rethink how you want to do this.

For further information, see Martina's blog: http://mhwelander.net/2014/04/09/sitecore-controller-rendering-action-results-what-can-i-return/